# Is there a way to include two (fully-automated) TOCs, one general and one detailed?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I'd like to have two TOCs in my document, first a general one with only the chapters and then a more detailed one with chapters and sections (and subsections and so on). If possible, I'd like them to be fully automated, by which I mean that I don't want to have to use `\addcontentsline` or similar commands every time I create a new chapter/section/whatever.

I have no idea how to go about this, otherwise I'd provide a MWE. I'm using the `book` class, but I'm willing to switch to another class if what I need is impossible in `book`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @cabohah Ah, yes, it does. The accepted answer didn't work for me, but Ivo's answer is incredibly elegant and does exactly what I needed. Thanks! (Also, that was quick!)